# Is it sinful to watch TV series The Young Pope?

Tags: catholicism, morality, entertainment

**Question:** Is it sinful to watch TV series [The Young Pope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Young_Pope)? Why? I did not watch the TV series, but from what I saw it seems morally corruptible.
I am interested in an answer from a Catholic viewpoint.

Comment: @Thom You really have to ask in the question itself, not just the tag. The show is about the Catholic Church - tagging doesn't indicate you want their perspective.

Answer (score 1):

**Is it sinful to watch TV series The Young Pope?**

**Possibly**?

Go and ask your local pastor if one is in doubt.

With a lack of clear papal or Vatican condemnation on the subject of the tv series ***The Young Pope***, each individual Catholic must follow the dictates of his or her conscience in regards to watching this series, aided with the council of a priest or pastor if necessary.

> The series has received five-star reviews, in the USA and in the UK, and even the Catholic Herald raved about the “mordantly funny story-telling” – but how has this subversive and thought-provoking drama been received in Italy?
>
> Unusually, for a Pope so brilliantly skilled in public relations, there has been no comment from Pope Francis, whose own gift for humility and skill at presentation – shunning the papal apartments for a basic hotel, driving a second-hand Volvo and washing the feet of the destitute – have won him millions of fans in spite of his ultra-conservative views on homosexuality.
>
> From the Vatican itself, there has been a resounding silence. I wonder why? When the first episode aired on Italian television, it was a huge hit, and received the highest rating ever for the first episode of a Sky drama. *The Young Pope* might masquerade as a high-budget soap – but it tells us some uncomfortable truths about the hypocrisy at the top of the Catholic Church. - [*The Young Pope is a hit with Catholics – so why is the Vatican so silent about it?*](https://www.independent.co.uk/voices/the-young-pope-pope-francis-catholic-church-sky-atlantic-jude-law-a7397371.html)

Comment: The would be a separate question and possibly be opinion based.